# how to execute nested? request in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Good day.
I have one table.
Please help me make a request.

1st request:

```
SELECT Name, Time FROM table1 WHERE Ongoing_ID IS NOT NULL
```

2st request:

```
SELECT Name, Time FROM table1 WHERE Disconnect_ID IS NOT NULL
```

how can i combine these two queries into one?
It is necessary to get values if Ongoing NOT NULL count >0 and Disconnect_ID NOT NULL count >0.
Those. I need to get values that both have values.
If disconnect_ID = 0, then it is not necessary
example sql table:

[image]

Comment: how? many different ways. depend on _what result_ you want to have.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not specify.
It is necessary to get values if Ongoing NOT NULL count >0 and Disconnect_ID NOT NULL count >0.
Those. I need to get values that both have values.
If disconnect_ID = 0, then it is not necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, use `and` in the `where` clause if you want both conditions to be true.

```
SELECT Name, Time 
FROM
    table1 
WHERE
    Disconnect_ID IS NOT NULL 
    and Ongoing_ID IS NOT NULL
```

If you want either condition, use `or`

```
SELECT Name, Time 
FROM
    table1 
WHERE
    Disconnect_ID IS NOT NULL 
    or Ongoing_ID IS NOT NULL
```

### Edit based on comment

```
SELECT Name, Time 
FROM
    table1 
WHERE
    Disconnect_ID > 0
    and Ongoing_ID > 0
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't specify the result I want to get.
If disconnect count> 0, and connect count> 0, then get all values

Comment: Check the updated answer. The greater than, less than comparisons, don't include null values.